# Open Popup, and trigger JS

Tags: javascript, html

I own a chrome extension, that just recently got its own webpage. I was wondering if I could open the link to download the extension and somehow at the same time, trigger the JS to download it.

```css
button {
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #3366ff

}
```

```html
<button href="javascript:;" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore','MyWindow','width=800','height=800'); return false;" >Install The Extension</button>
```

Basically, I would like to make the popup appear, but with a little bit of my own JS

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to start the download when someone hits your page. I think most browsers will prevent you from downloading a file without user input as a ways to prevent malicious downloads.

Comment: no, what I mean is if you click on the button to open in in the chrome web store, it would open the page as a popup and trigger some JS on the chrome page, to start the installation instead of manually clicking "Install" @SethMcClaine

Comment: What issue are you running into?

Comment: I just dont know how to @SethMcClaine

Comment: XSS/Cross Site Scripting will not let you execute JS on the Chrome store, no way around it.

Comment: Not possible, further what about people on IE and FF who find your page?

Comment: I may add my extension to their stores, and also, it will change the html so it is just a link @shadoe2020

Comment: You cannot change chrome webstore, security. I've already tried from Tampermonkey. Waste of time.

Comment: can I insert JS on most pages? @shadoe2020

Comment: For the mostpart. I use tampermonkey and can take over about any page, but you can't do the chrome webstore

Comment: ok, that makes sense.